# Dynamic list for MailChimp checkboxes

Tags: mailchimp

I have a newsletter sign up form on my website that presents the user with a list of checkboxes to select. The checkboxes are generated dynamically from my database. Other standards newsletter sign up fields, such as email, name, phone number, address, etc. exist in the sign up form, as well.

In MailChimp, I have created a List and have added custom fields to match my sign up form (e.g. phone number, address). I then looked at the `Embedded Forms` -> `Naked` to see the generated markup. It's easy enough to set the `name` attributes of the text fields on my sign up form to match those in MailChimp's.

The struggle for me now is the checkboxes. I cannot put the list of items for the checkboxes in MailChimp as they need to be dynamically generated from my database. I have added a checkbox field in MailChimp to see what `name` attribute it generates in hopes I could use it in my form; I see something like this:

```
<input id="mce-group[15757]-15757-0" name="group[15757][1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
```

In my sign up form, I tried something like this:

```
<input name="group[15757][]" type="checkbox" value="Apple">
```

When I signed up, "Apple" was not carried over.

**How do I capture checkbox items from my signup form into MailChimp?**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using interests -- you won't be able to pass custom values to those, as they are simply yes or no. You'd probably be better off using a merge field. Alternately, you can create the interests dynamically, but you'll need to write a script to do that, you won't be able to use the form builder directly.

Comment: What are interests? How can I create them dynamically? And how can I use merge fields?

Comment: Could I "tag" the list entries instead with these dynamic values?

Comment: Interests, AKA groups: http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/managing-subscribers/add-subscribers-to-groups . Merge fields won't allow for "tagging" behavior where a user can be assigned more than one value.

I would probably try to find away to avoid truly dynamic checkbox values. If you do need something like that, you're going to have to use the API to do it.